# Installing Tomcat6 using Opscode cookbook on CentOS 5.10

Tags: java, tomcat, chef-infra, yum, cookbook

I'm trying to install tomcat6 using opscode chef cookbook. I get following error.

```
Recipe: tomcat::default
  * package[tomcat6] action install
    * No version specified, and no candidate version available for tomcat6
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[tomcat6]'
================================================================================


Chef::Exceptions::Package
-------------------------
No version specified, and no candidate version available for tomcat6
```

Apparently there is no package named tomcat6 when I try yum install tomcat6. How to fix this ? I tried adding yum and yum-epel cookbooks but they are not a solution as they over-write my yum files. Is there a way I can source the tomcat package from a zip file in a URL and install using that by modifying opscode cookbook ?

Answer (score 0):

wrap that ospcode cookbook into yours and add following execution before invoking that `tomcat::default`

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d
wget 'http://www.jpackage.org/jpackage50.repo'
yum update
```

Answer (score 0):

to have available the tomcat6 package you got to add the jpackage repository.
I made a cookbook to add the repository in the rhel family.

https://github.com/psyreactor/yum-jpackage-cookbook

Just include yum-jpackage in your node's run_list.

In the readme.md are detail settings

sorry for my English
best regards